# How to compare elements in every permutation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, permutation

I need to solve this problem:

If we have a set A={a,b,c,d,e}, how to print all possible permutations of length 3, such that, "a" appears before "c", and "d" appears at most once.
Thanks. :)

I create list A={a,b,c,d,e} and then i generate all triples with Tuples[list, {3}] but i don't know how to compare elements in every permutation.

Comment: Did you try to answer it yourself?

Comment: Yes i try.I generate permutation but i don't know how to compare for example first and second element in every permutation.

Comment: Then that should be your question

Comment: I appreciate that this is my first question .thanks :D

Comment: A Hint for your homework: How could DeleteCases and a pattern help you with part of the problem? This might help you learn about pattern in Mathematica https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html Then perhaps you could use DeleteCases and another pattern to help with more of your problem.